# Invalid Syntax-Except Not (Python)

Tags: python

Here is the code:

```
def measure_lister(Location):
    dont_crash=os.listdir(Location)
    measure={}
    for name in dont_crash:
        temp=function("%s//%s"%(Location,name))
        measure[name]=temp
```

So dont_crash is just a list of file names in a directory, and the function is unimportant but it creates a tuple with three elements. Python keeps saying the last line is a syntax error. I tried the exact same code in the shell and it worked fine, but python still refuses to compile the code. help!

Edit: Here is the exact code:

```
def measure_lister(Location,Baseline):
    dont_crash=os.listdir(Location)
    measure={}
    for name in dont_crash:
        temp=f_measures("%s\\%s"%(Location,name),int(name[17:20],baseline_file=Baseline)
        measure[name]=temp
```

and here is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\owner\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:/Users/owner/Desktop/diff_output_all/lists.py", line 1210
    measure[name]=temp
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Show us the exact exception; the code *as posted*, has no syntax errors however. You probably should use `os.path.join(Location, name)` here instead of a string formatting operation.

Comment: Also, why do you use `//`? A single `/` will be ok, or `\\\` if you're on Windows.

Comment: I know its awkward, but for some reason none of my functions (this is one of many) work if I only use single slashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the function to this:

```
def measure_lister(Location,Baseline):
    dont_crash=os.listdir(Location)
    measure={}
    for name in dont_crash:
        temp=f_measures("%s\\%s"%(Location,name),int(name[17:20]),baseline_file=Baseline)
        measure[name]=temp
```

I think you are missing a ) in the call to function f_measures,

EDITED as Martijn suggested

Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm embarrassed. You're my hero, Sergio.

Comment: @user3556814 - don't feel embarrassed. Everyone forgets a closing parenthesis or brackets once in a while. Maybe it's time to invest on a good IDE that catches those missing parens.

Comment: It is the parenthesis of the `int()` call that is missing; `int(name[17:20])`.

Comment: Yes @MartijnPieters, that's correct. Let me correct that line and thanks!